# MessageDialog : how to stop the program until the user's answer?

Tags: qml

The MessageDialog QML help states : "Modality does not mean that there are any blocking calls to wait for the dialog to be accepted or rejected;"

So if modality does not this job, how can we stop the program until the user answers the question ? Is there a "pause" command or do we have to implement a timer and if so, how can we set it correctly ?

here is a dummy snippet of my code :

```
function mainFunction(Parameters)
{
    startingPoint = subFonction()
    ... 
}

function subFonction(){
    messageDialog.open()
    return position
}

MessageDialog {
    id: messageDialog
    title: qsTr("Title")
    icon: StandardIcon.Question
    text: qsTr("Choose your location")
    ...
    onAccepted: {
        close()
    }
    Component.onCompleted: visible = true
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: What do you mean when say "stop the program"?

Comment: if startingPoint = subfonction is line 10, the program does not execute the line 11 as long as startingPoint as not been implemented with the answer given by the user, after the messageDialog has been validated. I need to know this answer to continue the other steps.

Comment: Just move the things of `mainFunction()` that needs to be executed after getting the user input in `onAccepted`. This way you ensure it will be executed after the user has answered your question.

Comment: So... that is the whole main.qml to place after onAccepted. And it is a long one with about 300 lines. Could be ok for a small code but not in this case, I think. But in last the idea can be useful if call an other function to relaunch the rest of the code. Thanks for help. No more simple way ?